# Maintaining values of action variables in between different requests

Tags: struts2, action

I am struts2 for developing my application.
Sample code of action class would be

```
class sampleAction extends Action {
private List<Employee> employee;
public validate(){
--logic for validation
}
public String prepopulate(){
--logic for populating value of employee list
}
--getters and setters
}
```

Now my problem is on page load i call prepopulate function and populate the value of employee list. After page submit validate method is called and during that if some error happens control redirects to jsp. but this time the value of employee list is empty. I am using this list for autocompleter tag in struts2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used Struts 2 built-in validation mechanism, as I prefer client-side validation to avoid an extra round trip. This is purely a personal choice and not a standard.

First I will suggest you not to use `Action` and use `ActionSupport`: `ActionSupport` provides a lot of functionality out of the box and you need not to do everything yourself.

I am assuming that you are using `defaultStack` and if this is the case than it provides out of the box `Prepare Interceptor` which takes care of preparing any values before the action itself is called.

In your case, `validate` is called before the `execute` method, so you never will get a chance to re-fill the values you need in your JSP.

All you need to make sure that you have `prepare()` method in your action class. Here are more details for this interceptor:

[Prepare Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/prepare-interceptor.html)
[FAQ: How do we repopulate controls when validation fails](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html)

Comment: Relying *only* on client-side validation is a really bad idea--data *must* be validated on the server side whether or not client-side validation occurs.

Comment: @DaveNewton agree!!! but that should be once we have validated data as per the first check and since most of the validation framework do same for us.though we still check data for certain conditions at server side :0

Comment: thanks for your answer. In my page i want to populate some drop downs on jsp page load. I loading the jsp via a action method present in the same action class. Will the prepare method get called this case too? Or is it only called after form submit?

Comment: @user1061430: when you load the page it should be by some action class so you can always prepare your data there.`Prepare()` method will get called when you call your action and before `execute` methods get called so that if something fail still you have the chance to `init` your crucial data

Comment: Thanks umesh, I have followed ur advice :). I have one more doubt. Wouldnt it be better if i store the data in session and then take it from session rather then executing the same set of queries again and again. FYI i m using hibernate as my data layer.

Comment: if this is something applicable to whole application and not subjected to frequent change can store it in session else you can fetch data from the DB.Action layer need not to know how the data being fetched be it `Hibernate` or `JPA`  or plain data access API

Comment: No I meant use of Hibernate will reduce the number of DB access by storing the data to session cache, so i might not be a bad idea by repeatedly executing the prepare method. What do you think?

Comment: oh you are talking about hibernate cache? the first level cache is only for a unit of work but you can always go ahead with second level caching like `ehcache` or `oscache`.yes yu can reply on that caching for sure

Comment: @RachitAgrawal: if this solve your problem you can always mark the answer as accepted it will help other who have similar problem and stumble across your post